# One IF can have more than one ELSE clause ?? (c programming)

Tags: c

And does each expression in the `else if` must test the same variable ? Please give example for the second question.
And can any expression be used for the IF expression ?
And in SWITCH statement, each case can have only one statement or more ? If we can put more than 1 statement, then what is the syntax for it ?

```
case 1:
      printf("Blah Blah");
      printf("Blah blah blah");
```

Or

```
case 1:
      {
      printf("Blah Blah");
      printf("Blah blah blah");
      }
```

Yes these are all silly question's but I am still learning programming.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably ask your questions separately.

Comment: Why can't you try these yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### if, else, "else if"

An `if` can have zero or one associated `else` clauses. Examples:

```
if (X)
    printf("if\n");
```

or

```
if (X)
    printf("if\n");
else
    printf("else\n");
```

These take only a **single statement**. If you want to use multiple statements (and some people say it's better to do this even if you only have one statement per `if`/`else`), you have to use curly braces, like this:

```
if (X) {
    printf("if\n");
} else {
    printf("else\n");
}
```

You can also nest `if`s:

```
if (X)
    printf("X\n");
else
    if (Y)
        printf("Y\n");
    else
        printf("something else\n");
```

This is usually written in a more readable way, though:

```
if (X)
    printf("X\n");
else if (Y)
    printf("Y\n");
else
    printf("something else\n");
```

You see, the `else if` is nothing special, it's just another form of laying out a nested `if`.

Again, if you want more than one statement in there, you need to use curly braces:

```
if (X) {
    printf("X\n");
    printf("X2\n");
} else if (Y) {
    printf("Y\n");
    printf("Y2\n");
} else {
    printf("something else\n");
    printf("yet another print\n");
}
```

### switch/case

As for `switch` statements, there you don't need curly braces. Note however that "cases fall through" which means that in this example all four `printf`s are actually executed:

```
switch (1) {
  case 1:
    printf("I will be printed!\n");
    printf("Me too!\n");
  case 2:
    printf("And me also! (although I probably shouldn't)\n");
  case 3:
    printf("Me as well!\n");
}
```

If you don't want this (which is usually the case), you have to use an explicit `break` after the code in each `case`:

```
switch (1) {
  case 1:
    printf("I will be printed!\n");
    printf("Me too!\n");
    break;
  case 2:
    printf("I won't :(\n");
    break;
  case 3:
    printf("D'oh!\n");
    break;
}
```

### Blocks

By the way, the curly braces rule can be generalized: At every place where a single statement is allowed, you can also use something like `{ ... }`, which is called a **block**. The advantage of using blocks is that you can

1. Use multiple statements where only one would be allowed otherwise (e.g. in an `if`)
2. Declare variables at the beginning of every block! Thus, you can do something like the following `case 3: { int x = 3; printf("%d\n", x); }`.

Answer (score 0):

For switch case doubt, a case like `case 1:` works like a normal c label. You don't have to do anything to write a "block" of statements. It just continues to execute until the `swtich` block is over or a `break` statement is encountered. Even other cases on the way will be ignored.

so you can write you switch case like this:

```
case 1:
   printf("Blah Blah");
   printf("Blah Blah Blah");
   break; //This is important. Signifies end of block, not the braces!
```

There is no syntax that is meant for single statement separately. It all follows a pattern, once you get on hold to it, you will no longer have such doubts. I didn't get your `if...else` doubt, but I think it is similar. Think of it as how compiler would parse it and make meaning out of it, you will see things getting clear automatically.

Answer (score 0):

An `if` can not have more than one `else`.  However you can put a new `if` in the `else` case:

```
if (var == 0)
{
    doZero();
} 
else
{
   if (var > 10)
   {
       doTooBig();
   }
   else
   {
        doDefault();
   }
}
```

And people usually remove the brackets after the first else, so that it reads like this:

```
if (var == 0)
{
    doZero();
} 
else if (var > 10)
{
    doTooBig();
}
else
{
     doDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (i){
   case 1:
     state1;
     state2;
     state3;
     break;
}
```

Switch statements start executing code when you hit the matching case and then goes until it sees a break statement. This means if you forget the break the code will keep running through all of your cases until the end of the switch statement.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html

Answer (score 0):

1. No, there can be only one `else` per `if`.  Since an `else if` is a new `if`, it can have a new `else` - you can have as many `else if`s as you want.
2. No, you can put any condition in any `if` statement:

   ```
   if (foo)
     ...
   else if (bar)
     ...
   ```
3. Yes, any expression can be used in an `if` statement.
4. You can use as many statements as you like.  Both of your examples are fine, but the second one creates a new block - you could declare variables inside it, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the else if doesn't exists!
Writing this:

```
if(...) {

}
else if(...) {    // can test any condition, no need to use the same var.

}
else if(...) {

}
else if(...) {

}
else {

}
```

Is equivalent to (and understood by the compiler as):

```
if(...) {

}
else {
    if(...) {    // can test any condition, no need to use the same var.

    }
    else {
        if(...) {

        }
        else {
            if(...) {

            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why we write it like the first snippet is obvious: it's much more clear and readable.
Regarding your question about the switch statement, writing or not the parentheses doesn't make any difference.